Applying for a UK visitor visa. Should I mention I was previously refused a Turkish visa 2 years ago on the application?
I am applying for a UK visitor visa for my wife in order to appear for the PLAB 2 examination. We were refused a Turkish tourist visa in the past. Do I need to mention this on the UK visa application? It was because of incomplete documentation.


Do I need to mention this on the UK visa application?

Absolutely yes.There is a specific question about all prior visa history in the application. Not disclosing a refusal would be a disaster if UKVI discovered the deception. See for example UK visa refused under 3.6 a of Appendix V (deception)

It was because of incomplete documentation.

Explain the reason and, if you have it, provide the refusal letter.
Note the distinction between rejection and refusal. A rejection means the application was not accepted for processing for some reason (eg failure to give biometrics on time). A refusal means the application was accepted for processing and the outcome was a refusal/denial. Rejections do not need to be disclosed, refusals/denials do need to be disclosed.
